# How can i extract Dates from a string field in Hive using RegEx function

Tags: sql, date, hive, substring, hiveql

```
'2021 july (JNS) Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/26/2021 and 8/6/2021'
```

Expected result:

```
Date1 : 7/26/2021
Date2 : 8/6/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

```
select regexp_extract(str, '(?i)BETWEEN (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1) as date1,
       regexp_extract(str, '(?i)AND (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})$',1) as date2
```

And if you need to convert dates to correct format (yyyy-MM-dd) use split to get all date elements in the array, use lpad to add zeroes and concatenate:

```
with mydata as (
select '2021 july (JNS) Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/26/2021 and 8/6/2021' str
)
select concat(date1[2],'-',lpad(date1[0],2,0),'-',lpad(date1[1],2,0)) as date1,
       concat(date2[2],'-',lpad(date2[0],2,0),'-',lpad(date2[1],2,0)) as date2
from
(
select split(date1,'/') date1, split(date2,'/') date2 --arrays
  from
    (select regexp_extract(str, '(?i)BETWEEN (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1) as date1,
            regexp_extract(str, '(?i)AND (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})$',1) as date2
       from mydata
    ) s 
)s
```

Result:

```
date1       date2
2021-07-26  2021-08-06
```

If there are strings without BETWEEN and AND and you want to extract first and second dates from the beginning of the string, use this:

```
select regexp_extract(str, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1) as date1,
       regexp_extract(str, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',2) as date2
```

You can make second date optional by adding * after second group, first date will be extracted even if second date does not exist in the string:

```
select regexp_extract(str, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})*',1) as date1,
       regexp_extract(str, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',2) as date2
```

Comment: That Works.If i dont have BETWEEN and AND in other string columns how can this be a dynamic

Comment: @JayaprakashNeela Added to the answer